# Where can I find information on comparing two MacBook Pro models?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm thinking about getting a MacBook Pro, one of the 15" ones in the low end of the spectrum.

I can see two models in on-line shops that match my price range (namely, the MD318D/A and the MC723D/A). One model is 100 euros cheaper than the other, but weirdly, *it seems to have the better specs*: the MC723D/A comes with a 750GB hard drive as opposed to 500GB.

All the other specs seem identical, down to the size of the L6 cache, the processor, and the make and model of the graphics adapter. The only special thing the expensive one seems to have is OS X Lion instead of Snow Leopard. Can the software update account for a hundred euro's difference?

Here are the data sheets I'm comparing: [MD318D](http://www.amazon.de/Apple-MacBook-MD318D-Notebook-i7-2675QM/dp/tech-data/B005YYTIOG/ref=de_a_smtd), [MC723D](http://www.amazon.de/Apple-MacBook-MC723D-Notebook-2720QM/dp/tech-data/B004P8JHSY/ref=de_a_smtd) - German only, sorry,  Amazon.com doesn't seem to have them.

Where can I find reliable information on each generation so I can figure out whether the price difference is justified or not, and what the extra €100 would actually get me?

Comment: ignore my other comment, it looks like MD318D is newer than MC723D. (I didn't read the number well enough). The two models are very similar. I would just get the cheaper one unless the newer one has a better warraunty.

Comment: @user thanks! Looking at the comparisons, I was thinking the same thing - €100 is a lot of dough, and whether the CPU is a few percent slower than the other one's is unlikely to affect me much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trust the english Wikipedia on [technical specs about the Macbook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_2).

Answer (score 3):

Try this
http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_capability/mac-specs-by-machine-model-machine-id.html

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. The differences seem to be minimal ones in the graphics and processor departments.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [EveryMac.com's Ultimate Mac Comparison](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-comparison-chart/) tool that lets you pick and compare between any set of Mac hardware. Just pick the models you want and your off to comparing.

Additionally, make note of the [Geekbench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/) results listed on EveryMac's specs pages and comparisons, its a very useful indicator of raw processing capabilities, the higher the number the faster the machine is.

[image: pointing out geekbench results on everymac]

Answer (score 1):

They have slightly different processors -- check http://ark.intel.com/products/53470/Intel-Core-i7-2675QM-Processor-(6M-Cache-2_20-GHz) and  http://ark.intel.com/products/50067/Intel-Core-i7-2720QM-Processor-(6M-Cache-2_20-GHz).  The differences are that the 2720 has a better max turbo speed (in some conditions, it will be faster), supports faster ram (which you will probably not use), and has a slightly better integrated gpu.  Amusingly, it appears that the cheaper computer has the better processor.